# JSP pages don't see css

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

It's only problem with visability of css. There are a lot of answers in google, but since yesterday I've checked all of them and I still didn't solve my problem...

My project structure in eclipse looks like this:

[image]

Only in one file I have relation to css - in header.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css1/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css1/main.css"/>
```

This path should be fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm building a dynamic web project using JSP and Tomcat 9.0 in Eclipse. The JSP-pages are working properly, but they don't find the CSS-file. I'm not using a web.xml.

Comment: Have you (re)published your project to server after adding CSS?

Answer (score 1):

In jsp also you can use the Html tags freely so just use

```
<link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/resources/css1/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
```

i think this should work, see that you are not making spelling mistakes or Capital/small alphabet mistakes.